# Django not finding database despite it existing

Tags: python, mysql, database

I'm trying to change the default database used in Django to MySQL, I've adjusted my `settings.py` file like so:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'clients',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3307',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
    }
}
```

I'm still getting the `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'clients'")`. When I try to connect to the `'mysql'` database that comes default with MySQL I have no issue. I get this error when I try to use `manage.py makemigrations`,`migrations` or `runserver`. I have `MySQL-Python` installed and everything. Proof that my `clients` database exists:

[image]

Comment: mysql port is 3306

Comment: Okay that worked, thanks. But I changed my port number to 3307 in XAMPP a while ago, so why wasn't that working?

Comment: That sounds like another question to me... But make sure you restarted everything first.

Comment: Ahh I hate starting new questions so much lol. Okay MySQL is on server 3306 and the MySQL in XAMPP says 3307, whats the difference? Or should I still start a new question? lol

Comment: That basically means you have two instances of mysql running, one from xampp and one i am assuming is your server wide installation. Maybe you can shut one down. Restart xampp with mysql running on 3307 and this should work.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but that would make sense wouldn't it? Isn't port 3307 the MySQL instance that doesn't have any custom DBs? The only instance I used was the one on port 3306